# How to Interpolate and animate Progress Bar? "import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';"

Tags: react-native, progress-bar, interpolation, react-animated

Good morning friends, good ... what happens is this: I tried to make a logic so that the setLoaded changes the value of my progress bar, and when the value of it reaches 100, it shows the Modal. But nothing is happening.  I wanted when I pressed the play button my ProgressBar to start loading its value, and when I clicked the pause button the value of it would stop at the value it was. Will someone help me please? I've worked very hard, I'm getting discouraged
I want activate this through Play button (touchable opacity)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text, View, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { Entypo, Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

import { Card } from 'react-native-shadow-cards';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import  Modal from 'react-native-modal';

//link redefinir senha
//https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx
const taskDetails = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigation(); 
  const [showHide, setShowHide] = useState(false);
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false); 
  return (
    
    <>
    {
    !isLoaded ?
    <Modal isVisible={modal}>
    <View 
    style={{
    backgroundColor: '#fff', 
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 15,
    height: 480,
    width: 300}}>
       <Image
        source={require('../../assets/images/working-hours(1).png')}
        style={{alignSelf: 'center',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        margin: 10,
        marginTop: 20}}/>
        <Text style={{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        padding: 10,

        }}>
        {'Eba! \n Task finalizada com sucesso!'}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
         {'Suas horas nesta task foram \n lançadas,volte para a home para \n começar uma nova tarefa!'}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{
            textAlign: 'center', color: '#808080', 
            padding: 5, marginBottom: 10 }}>
            Com isso você ganhou:
        </Text>
        <Image
            source={require('../../assets/images/grin-stars.png')}
        style={{
        alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 75,
         margin: 5}}/>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'right', marginRight: 95,
                bottom: 40}}>
            10pts
        </Text>
        <Text style={{
        textAlign: 'right', fontSize: 12,
         marginRight: 70, bottom: 45}}>
            de experiência
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 10,
        width: 250,
        height: 50,
        elevation: 8, 
        bottom: 30 
        }}
        onPress={() => setModal(false)}>
            <Text style={{
                color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                }}>
                    Fechar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    </Modal>
    
    :  <Progress.Bar progress={progress} 
    width={200}
    color={'#A0D800'}
    backgroundColor={'#ECECEC'}
    borderColor={'transparent'}
    height={10}
    borderRadius={10}
    style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
    bottom={20}
    
     />
    }

      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{
        flex: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }}>
        <ScrollView >
   
            <View>
       

        <TouchableOpacity>
              <Card style={{ margin: 20, height: 450,
             }}>
           <Feather name={'file-text'}
           color={'#F2CB1D'} 
           size={20}
           style={{paddingLeft: 20, 
           top: 20,}}/>
            <Text
            style={{paddingLeft: 50}}>Task 59788</Text>
            <Entypo name={'controller-record'}
            style={{paddingLeft: 270, bottom: 14
           }}
            color={'#007ACC'}
            size={10}
            />
            <Text
            style={{paddingLeft: 290, bottom: 30}}
            >Active</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12,
            paddingLeft: 20, bottom: 15
            }}>App corporativo OnlineTeam</Text>
            <Text style={{
                paddingLeft: 20, fontSize: 20,
                 bottom: 10}}>
                    Criar telas no Figma</Text>
            <Text style={{
                paddingLeft: 20, 
            fontSize: 12}}>
                Original Estimate: 4h</Text>
            <Text style={{
                paddingLeft: 250,bottom: 17,
                 fontSize: 12}}>
            Completed: 2h</Text>
    
            <Text style={{textAlign: 'left',
            bottom: 10, fontSize: 10,
             paddingLeft: 55}}>
            0%</Text> 
            <Progress.Bar progress={progress} 
            width={200}
            color={'#A0D800'}
            backgroundColor={'#ECECEC'}
            borderColor={'transparent'}
            height={10}
            borderRadius={10}
            style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
            bottom={20}
            
             />

             <Text style={{textAlign: 'right',
              fontSize: 10,bottom: 35, 
              paddingRight: 45}}>
              100%</Text>
              <View
                style={{
                    borderBottomColor: '#ECECEC',
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    marginBottom: 20,
                    width: 300,
                    
                }}
                />
              <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color: "#A0D800",
              paddingLeft: 20, }}>
                Detalhes da task</Text>
              <Text style={{color: "#808080", alignContent: 'center',
              padding: 15}}>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae enim nisl. 
                Proin iaculis eu felis sed cursus. In facilisis eleifend nisl,
                 at efficitur diam placerat ut. Aliquam neque nulla, convallis
                  a eleifend eget, elementum ut quam. Aliquam gravida mauris
                   auctor, gravida nisi vel, lobortis tellus. Donec ac velit vulputate, 
                   dictum neque vitae, tempus velit. Donec placerat in mauris vel porttitor. 
                   Mauris viverra ante a suscipit gravida. Mauris fringilla erat felis, eu 
                   facilisis erat laoreet ultrices.
              </Text>
          </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={{
                borderRadius: 10,
                alignItems: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#A0D800",
                height: 50, width: 50,marginLeft: 25
              }}
              onPress = { () => setLoaded(isLoaded)
              }>
                <Image
                source={require('../../assets/images/play(1).png')}
                style={{alignSelf: 'center',padding: 5,
                marginTop: 15}}/>

        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={{
                backgroundColor: "#000000",
                height: 50, width: 300,marginLeft: 20,
                borderRadius: 10, alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                bottom: 50, marginRight: 20
              }}>
              
                <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingTop: 10,
                margin: 5
            
                }}>
                    Pausar task
                </Text>
                <Image
                source={require('../../assets/images/pause.png')}
                    style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginRight: 15,
                    bottom: 25, marginLeft: 75}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
         
              </View>  


        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    </>
  )
}

export default taskDetails;
```

Comment: I tried to follow the logic of this site, however do not know how it applies to react native https://www.webtips.dev/how-to-make-a-download-progress-indicator-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this should work, but you should be able to debug your own program.

One thing I see is `setLoaded(isLoaded)`, and that is doing nothing. You are setting the state with the old state, nothing will happen. Try `setLoaded(!isLoaded)` to make it toggle. If state does not change, no re-render will happen.

Comment: @Balsa Kranenburg Doesn't works :(

Comment: eu quero alterar a lógica neste botão, queria que ao clicar nele o a barra da progress bar começasse no zero e proseguisse até o 100, in OnPress.   <TouchableOpacity style={{
                backgroundColor: "#000000",
                height: 50, width: 300,marginLeft: 20,
                borderRadius: 10, alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                bottom: 50, marginRight: 20
              }}
              onPress={() => setModal(true)}>

Comment: And when the value reaches 100, the modal appears

Comment: I want the progress bar like a download progress

Answer (score 0):

and I was based on that logic

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false); 100

{
    !isLoaded ?
    <Progress.Bar progress = {progress} width={null} />
    :  null
}
<Progress.Bar progress = {progress} width={null} />
onLoadProgress={(nativeEvent) => setProgress(nativeEvent.progress)}
onLoadEnd ={() => setLoaded(true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was wondering how to add this in the logic of my code

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}


const App = () => {
  let animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  useInterval(() => {
    if(progress < 100) {
      setProgress(progress + 5);
    }
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animation.current, {
      toValue: progress,
      duration: 100
    }).start();
  },[progress])

  const width = animation.current.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: ["0%", "100%"],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  })
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        Loading…..
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.progressBar}>
        <Animated.View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill], {backgroundColor: "#8BED4F", width }}/>
      </View>
      <Text>
        {`${progress}%`}
      </Text>

    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'Column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  progressBar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 20,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5
  }
});
```